# YouTubePartner.php not found

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

Our main goal is to upload audio references to match and automatically claim videos in Youtube. We work ok PHP.

We’re following this example:
[Uploading a new reference, so YouTube can automatically generate claims for newly uploaded videos on behalf of the asset's owner]
https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/code_samples/php#uploading_a_new_reference__so_youtube_can_automatically_generate_claims_for_newly_uploaded_videos_on_behalf_of_the_asset_s_owner
(second half of the doc):

```
// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTubePartner.php'; // <--- This file doesn't exist!
session_start();
```

We got it through the old API (Google API PHP Client 0.6.7) and the "Google_YouTubePartnerService.php" file we found here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/client_libraries , but this isn’t useful because we need "Service account" authentication, and the API doesn’t work with this.

So, we tried with Google API PHP Client 1.0.0 unsuccessfully. We get the authentication but we need to find this file `Google/Service/YouTubePartner.php` called by the example on the URL mentioned above: https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/code_samples/php#uploading_a_new_reference__so_youtube_can_automatically_generate_claims_for_newly_uploaded_videos_on_behalf_of_the_asset_s_owner

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Content ID PHP library wasn't updated for 1.0 version on the site.
Just got it updated. Thanks for the warning. https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/clientlib/Google-youtubePartner-v1-20140110-php-1.0.0-alpha.zip

Comment: First example at https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/code_samples/php works ok.

However, we need to execute the last (third) example on that page And we can’t, because it drops an error:

The step 3 in the code example is where we find this problem:


"An client error occurred: Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets/A767977048508576/ownership?onBehalfOfContentOwner=Altafonte: (400) You cannot identify a <code><a href="/youtube/partner/docs/v1/publishers">publisher</a></code> as the owner of a non-composition asset."
Could you help us please?

Comment: Are you using the latest version from here: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client   There was a bug about the library itself, and they fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Yes, with the last version the error continues... Any idea?

Comment: Please, we're waiting your answer to this... Any help?

Comment: If you need the fix immediately, you can use his branch.
https://github.com/ianbarber/google-api-php-client

Comment: Is there any update on this? I still don't see the referenced YouTubePartner.php in the repo, but its in the docs.

Comment: You can always find them in here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/client_libraries  They won't be in any other repo.